# How to write numpy.array() output literally to text file

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following function in python:

```
 def writeWinningBoards():
    f = open("goodBoards.txt", "a")
    for row in tableros:
        for index, value in enumerate(row):
            if value == 1:
                row[index] = 'x'
            elif value == 2:
                row[index] = ' '
            elif value == 3:
                row[index] = 'o'
        row = np.array(row).reshape(3,3)
        f.write(row)
        print row
    f.close()
```

How can a I write to a file, the console representation of the array, when row is printed I have this:

```
 ['o' 'o' 'x']
 ['x' 'x' 'x']
 ['o' 'x' 'o']
```

but in the file I get something like this:

```
 x    o   x      o x        x o      xo    o  x
```

How could I do this ? I just want a user-friendly way of storing tic tac toe gameboards for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Many ways, the one I'd suggest is:

```
row_reshaped = np.array(row).reshape(3,3)
row_reshaped_as_base_array = row_reshaped.tolist()
row_reshaped_as_json = json.dumps(row_reshaped_as_base_array
with open("goodBoards.txt", "a") as f:
   f.write(row_reshaped_as_json)
```

I don't do method chaining and find list comprehensions a bit too terse for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = np.array([["x", "o"], ["o", "x"]])

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df.to_csv("my_file.txt", header=False, index=False, sep=" ")
```

Result:

```
$ cat my_file.txt
x o
o x
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `f.write(row)` and `print row` isn't just that one writes to a file and the other writes to the screen.  In python, the `print` statement will append a newline after each call, whereas the `write` method on an open file object will not.

Comment: This isn't' an answer.